# Clusters does not appear on my map with scatter Mapbox

Tags: plotly, mapbox, scatter

I met an issue about my scatter Mapbox with Plotly.Clusters does not appear (whereas the labels appears when I fly over with computer mouse...) though my code is ok (I work on Jupiter notebook):

```
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(df2, lat="Lat", lon="Lon", zoom=8, color = "Cluster_KMeans", mapbox_style="carto-positron")
fig.show()
```

imported librairies

```
! pip install plotly
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = "iframe_connected"
```

Many thanks for your help !

Comment: Your code isn't [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) because without knowing what `df2` looks like, we can't reproduce your issue. Can you post a sample of your DataFrame, as well as a screenshot to more clearly explain your problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- you have not defined `df2` in your question.  I can imply it has three columns from your code: *Lat, Lon, Cluster_KMeans*.  Hence have sourced some locations and added a column of random values
- generated figure using your code.  It works as expected.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df2 = pd.read_html("https://www.latlong.net/category/cities-235-15.html")[0].rename(columns={"Latitude":"Lat", "Longitude":"Lon"})
df2["Cluster_KMeans"] = np.random.randint(1,5,len(df2))
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(df2, lat="Lat", lon="Lon", zoom=8, color = "Cluster_KMeans", mapbox_style="carto-positron")
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Rob , thank you for your reply but does not work. I have indeed 3 columns and df2 is well defined.I ll check again

Comment: I can look into *does not work* if you are specific about what is not working.  1) figure fails to build due to exceptions? 2) figure builds but is blank? 3) hover data is not what you expect? 4) color scheme does not match your requirements 5) laptop powered off :-) , etc... need something to go on

Comment: Hello Rob, I switched to Google Colab instead of Jupyter and it runs